# Is there a String.Remove() equivalent for Java?

Tags: java, string

Is there a C#'s [`String.Remove()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.remove?view=netcore-3.1) equivalent for Java?

I never had any problems with doing `string.Remove(text.Length, text.Length)` and I would know if there were the same equivalent to this in Java.

Example:

```
string text = "abcdef";
text = text.Remove(text.Length / 2, text.Length / 2); // becomes abc
```

Comment: There’s a String API doc which might be of value. Ironically I’m too lazy to paste in the URL.

Comment: @DaveNewton There you go: [`String#substring`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#substring(int))

Comment: Please note that you're [expected](http://idownvotedbecau.se/noresearch/) to research this on your own prior to posting here.

Comment: @ShiningLea While I didn’t express it in an acceptable way, my point is this: I, personally, prefer due diligence. SO also expects a certain amount of research before asking a question like this, which is both trivially searchable (even after allowing the idea that looking at the String Javadocs isn’t the most pleasant way to spend a couple of minutes (although doing so is instructive being the immediate need)) and duplicated here and elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

Such a function is not part of the [`String`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html) class and I'm not aware of any other utility classes that provide this.

But you can always write your own version of it:

```
public static String remove(String str, int startIndex, int count) {
    return str.substring(0, startIndex) + str.substring(startIndex + count);
}
```

Or if you want to use the single parameter overload of the `String.Remove` (which seems to suffice in your example), it's even easier:

```
str.substring(0, startIndex);
```